# redox reactions with arrows and enumeration using chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I'm using the `chemmacros` package and I'd like to have a counter on the left of the following equation:

[image]

I've tried using the `\begin{reactions}` command but I only get this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the first equation (with arrows) with the numeration from the last one.

Here's my code for the last equation:

```
\begin{reactions}
    H2O + "\OX{o1,\ox*{+4,S}\ox*{-2,O2}}" \gas{} + "\OX{r1,\ox*{0,I2}}" \aq{} ^
    ->
    H2 "\OX{o2,\ox*{+6,S}\ox*{-2,O4}}" \aq{} + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox*{+1,H}\ox*{-1,I}}" \aq{}
\end{reactions}
\redox(o1,o2)[->]{\small Oxidation: $- 2\el$}
\redox(r1,r2)[->][-1]{\small Reduktion: $+ 2\el$}
```

Replacing `\begin{reactions}` with `\ch{` and `\end{reactions}` with `}` will give equation 1 again. Putting `\end{reactions}` at the very bottom of the code provided will give a bunch of errors. I'd really appreciate any help.

P.S. Don't mind the validity of the equation.

Comment: As long as the numbering is continued orderly `reaction` would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the `\redox...` calls *inside* the `reaction` (or `reactions`) environment but also escape them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{redox,reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  H2O + "\OX{o1,\ox*{+4,S}\ox*{-2,O2}}" \gas{} + "\OX{r1,\ox*{0,I2}}" \aq{} ^
    ->
  H2 "\OX{o2,\ox*{+6,S}\ox*{-2,O4}}" \aq{} + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox*{+1,H}\ox*{-1,I}}" \aq{}
  "\redox(o1,o2)[->]{\small Oxidation: $- 2\el$}"
  "\redox(r1,r2)[->][-1]{\small Reduktion: $+ 2\el$}"
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]